# How reload interrupt in real mode?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, interrupt

I am creating an operating system and I want to call the bios in protected mode, so I switch back to real mode, and I call the bios, but when I try to call the bios my emulator bochs write that as loop :

```
00002065173i[CPU0 ] BxError: instruction with opcode=0xff
00002065173i[CPU0 ] mod was c0, nnn was 7, rm was 7
00002065173i[CPU0 ] WARNING: Encountered an unknown instruction (signalling illegal instruction)
```

My code to call the bios is:

```
[bits 32]

global int32, _int32

struc regs16_t
    .di resw 1
    .si resw 1
    .bp resw 1
    .sp resw 1
    .bx resw 1
    .dx resw 1
    .cx resw 1
    .ax resw 1
    .gs resw 1
    .fs resw 1
    .es resw 1
    .ds resw 1
    .ef resw 1
endstruc

%define INT32_BASE                         0x7C00
%define REBASE(x)                          (((x) - reloc) + INT32_BASE)
%define GDTENTRY(x)                        ((x) << 3)
%define CODE32                             GDTENTRY(1)  ; 0x08
%define DATA32                             GDTENTRY(2)  ; 0x10
%define CODE16                             GDTENTRY(3)  ; 0x18
%define DATA16                             GDTENTRY(4)  ; 0x20
%define STACK16                            (INT32_BASE - regs16_t_size)

section .text
    int32: use32                             ; by Napalm
    _int32:
        cli                                    ; disable interrupts
        pusha                                  ; save register state to 32bit stack
        mov  esi, reloc                        ; set source to code below
        mov  edi, INT32_BASE                   ; set destination to new base address
        mov  ecx, (int32_end - reloc)          ; set copy size to our codes size
        cld                                    ; clear direction flag (so we copy forward)
        rep  movsb                             ; do the actual copy (relocate code to low 16bit space)
        jmp INT32_BASE                         ; jump to new code location
    reloc: use32                             ; by Napalm
        mov  [REBASE(stack32_ptr)], esp        ; save 32bit stack pointer
        sidt [REBASE(idt32_ptr)]               ; save 32bit idt pointer
        sgdt [REBASE(gdt32_ptr)]               ; save 32bit gdt pointer
        lgdt [REBASE(gdt16_ptr)]               ; load 16bit gdt pointer
        lea  esi, [esp+0x24]                   ; set position of intnum on 32bit stack
        lodsd                                  ; read intnum into eax
        mov  [REBASE(ib)], al                  ; set intrrupt immediate byte from our arguments 
        mov  esi, [esi]                        ; read regs pointer in esi as source
        mov  edi, STACK16                      ; set destination to 16bit stack
        mov  ecx, regs16_t_size                ; set copy size to our struct size
        mov  esp, edi                          ; save destination to as 16bit stack offset
        rep  movsb                             ; do the actual copy (32bit stack to 16bit stack)
        jmp  word CODE16:REBASE(p_mode16)      ; switch to 16bit selector (16bit protected mode)
    p_mode16: use16
        mov  ax, DATA16                        ; get our 16bit data selector
        mov  ds, ax                            ; set ds to 16bit selector
        mov  es, ax                            ; set es to 16bit selector
        mov  fs, ax                            ; set fs to 16bit selector
        mov  gs, ax                            ; set gs to 16bit selector
        mov  ss, ax                            ; set ss to 16bit selector
        mov  eax, cr0                          ; get cr0 so we can modify it
        and  al,  ~0x01                        ; mask off PE bit to turn off protected mode
        mov  cr0, eax                          ; set cr0 to result
        jmp  word 0x0000:REBASE(r_mode16)      ; finally set cs:ip to enter real-mode
    r_mode16: use16
        xor  ax, ax                            ; set ax to zero
        mov  ds, ax                            ; set ds so we can access idt16
        mov  ss, ax                            ; set ss so they the stack is valid
        lidt [REBASE(idt16_ptr)]               ; load 16bit idt
        mov  bx, 0x0870                        ; master 8 and slave 112
        call resetpic                          ; set pic's the to real-mode settings
        popa                                   ; load general purpose registers from 16bit stack
        pop  gs                                ; load gs from 16bit stack
        pop  fs                                ; load fs from 16bit stack
        pop  es                                ; load es from 16bit stack
        pop  ds                                ; load ds from 16bit stack
        sti                                    ; enable interrupts
        db 0xCD                                ; opcode of INT instruction with immediate byte
    ib: db 0x00
        cli                                    ; disable interrupts
        xor  sp, sp                            ; zero sp so we can reuse it
        mov  ss, sp                            ; set ss so the stack is valid
        mov  sp, INT32_BASE                    ; set correct stack position so we can copy back
        pushf                                  ; save eflags to 16bit stack
        push ds                                ; save ds to 16bit stack
        push es                                ; save es to 16bit stack
        push fs                                ; save fs to 16bit stack
        push gs                                ; save gs to 16bit stack
        pusha                                  ; save general purpose registers to 16bit stack
        mov  bx, 0x2028                        ; master 32 and slave 40
        call resetpic                          ; restore the pic's to protected mode settings
        mov  eax, cr0                          ; get cr0 so we can modify it
        inc  eax                               ; set PE bit to turn on protected mode
        mov  cr0, eax                          ; set cr0 to result
        jmp  dword CODE32:REBASE(p_mode32)     ; switch to 32bit selector (32bit protected mode)
    p_mode32: use32
        mov  ax, DATA32                        ; get our 32bit data selector
        mov  ds, ax                            ; reset ds selector
        mov  es, ax                            ; reset es selector
        mov  fs, ax                            ; reset fs selector
        mov  gs, ax                            ; reset gs selector
        mov  ss, ax                            ; reset ss selector
        lgdt [REBASE(gdt32_ptr)]               ; restore 32bit gdt pointer
        lidt [REBASE(idt32_ptr)]               ; restore 32bit idt pointer
        mov  esp, [REBASE(stack32_ptr)]        ; restore 32bit stack pointer
        mov  esi, STACK16                      ; set copy source to 16bit stack
        lea  edi, [esp+0x28]                   ; set position of regs pointer on 32bit stack
        mov  edi, [edi]                        ; use regs pointer in edi as copy destination
        mov  ecx, regs16_t_size                ; set copy size to our struct size
        cld                                    ; clear direction flag (so we copy forward)
        rep  movsb                             ; do the actual copy (16bit stack to 32bit stack)
        popa                                   ; restore registers
        sti                                    ; enable interrupts
        ret                                    ; return to caller
        
    resetpic:                                ; reset's 8259 master and slave pic vectors
        push ax                                ; expects bh = master vector, bl = slave vector
        mov  al, 0x11                          ; 0x11 = ICW1_INIT | ICW1_ICW4
        out  0x20, al                          ; send ICW1 to master pic
        out  0xA0, al                          ; send ICW1 to slave pic
        mov  al, bh                            ; get master pic vector param
        out  0x21, al                          ; send ICW2 aka vector to master pic
        mov  al, bl                            ; get slave pic vector param
        out  0xA1, al                          ; send ICW2 aka vector to slave pic
        mov  al, 0x04                          ; 0x04 = set slave to IRQ2
        out  0x21, al                          ; send ICW3 to master pic
        shr  al, 1                             ; 0x02 = tell slave its on IRQ2 of master
        out  0xA1, al                          ; send ICW3 to slave pic
        shr  al, 1                             ; 0x01 = ICW4_8086
        out  0x21, al                          ; send ICW4 to master pic
        out  0xA1, al                          ; send ICW4 to slave pic
        pop  ax                                ; restore ax from stack
        ret                                    ; return to caller
        
    stack32_ptr:                             ; address in 32bit stack after we
        dd 0x00000000                          ;   save all general purpose registers
        
    idt32_ptr:                               ; IDT table pointer for 32bit access
        dw 0x0000                              ; table limit (size)
        dd 0x00000000                          ; table base address
        
    gdt32_ptr:                               ; GDT table pointer for 32bit access
        dw 0x0000                              ; table limit (size)
        dd 0x00000000                          ; table base address
        
    idt16_ptr:                               ; IDT table pointer for 16bit access
        dw 0x03FF                              ; table limit (size)
        dd 0x00000000                          ; table base address
        
    gdt16_base:                              ; GDT descriptor table
        .null:                                 ; 0x00 - null segment descriptor
            dd 0x00000000                        ; must be left zero'd
            dd 0x00000000                        ; must be left zero'd
            
        .code32:                               ; 0x01 - 32bit code segment descriptor 0xFFFFFFFF
            dw 0xFFFF                            ; limit  0:15
            dw 0x0000                            ; base   0:15
            db 0x00                              ; base  16:23
            db 0x9A                              ; present, iopl/0, code, execute/read
            db 0xCF                              ; 4Kbyte granularity, 32bit selector; limit 16:19
            db 0x00                              ; base  24:31
            
        .data32:                               ; 0x02 - 32bit data segment descriptor 0xFFFFFFFF
            dw 0xFFFF                            ; limit  0:15
            dw 0x0000                            ; base   0:15
            db 0x00                              ; base  16:23
            db 0x92                              ; present, iopl/0, data, read/write
            db 0xCF                              ; 4Kbyte granularity, 32bit selector; limit 16:19
            db 0x00                              ; base  24:31
            
        .code16:                               ; 0x03 - 16bit code segment descriptor 0x000FFFFF
            dw 0xFFFF                            ; limit  0:15
            dw 0x0000                            ; base   0:15
            db 0x00                              ; base  16:23
            db 0x9A                              ; present, iopl/0, code, execute/read
            db 0x0F                              ; 1Byte granularity, 16bit selector; limit 16:19
            db 0x00                              ; base  24:31
            
        .data16:                               ; 0x04 - 16bit data segment descriptor 0x000FFFFF
            dw 0xFFFF                            ; limit  0:15
            dw 0x0000                            ; base   0:15
            db 0x00                              ; base  16:23
            db 0x92                              ; present, iopl/0, data, read/write
            db 0x0F                              ; 1Byte granularity, 16bit selector; limit 16:19
            db 0x00                              ; base  24:31
            
    gdt16_ptr:                               ; GDT table pointer for 16bit access
        dw gdt16_ptr - gdt16_base - 1          ; table limit (size)
        dd gdt16_base                          ; table base address
        
    int32_end:                               ; end marker (so we can copy the code)
```

and the only code befor in the kernel is my gdt init:

```
#include "../types/types.h"
#include "../lib/lib.h"

#define __GDT__
#include "gdt.h"

void init_gdt_desc(u32 base, u32 limite, u8 acces, u8 other,
                   struct gdtdesc *desc)
{
    desc->lim0_15 = (limite & 0xffff);
    desc->base0_15 = (base & 0xffff);
    desc->base16_23 = (base & 0xff0000) >> 16;
    desc->acces = acces;
    desc->lim16_19 = (limite & 0xf0000) >> 16;
    desc->other = (other & 0xf);
    desc->base24_31 = (base & 0xff000000) >> 24;
    return;
}

void init_gdt(void)
{
    
    default_tss.debug_flag = 0x00;
    default_tss.io_map = 0x00;
    default_tss.esp0 = 0x20000;
    default_tss.ss0 = 0x18;

    init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, &kgdt[0]);
    init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0x9B, 0x0D, &kgdt[1]);      
    init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0x93, 0x0D, &kgdt[2]);    
    init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0x0, 0x97, 0x0D, &kgdt[3]);          

    //user segment
    init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFF, 0x9E, 0x0, &kgdt[4]); /* ucode */
    init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFF, 0x92, 0x0, &kgdt[5]); /* udata */
    //normal gdt
    //init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0xFF, 0x0D, &kgdt[4]); /* ucode */
    //init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0xFFFFF, 0xF3, 0x0D, &kgdt[5]); /* udata */
    init_gdt_desc(0x0, 0x0, 0xF7, 0x0D, &kgdt[6]);      /* ustack */

    init_gdt_desc((u32) &default_tss, 0x67, 0xE9, 0x00, &kgdt[7]); /*TSS*/

    kgdtr.limite = GDTSIZE * 8;
    kgdtr.base = GDTBASE;

    memcpy((char *) kgdtr.base, (char *) kgdt, kgdtr.limite);

    asm("lgdtl (kgdtr)");

    asm("   movw $0x10, %ax \n \
            movw %ax, %ds       \n \
            movw %ax, %es       \n \
            movw %ax, %fs       \n \
            movw %ax, %gs       \n \
            ljmp $0x08, $next   \n \
            next:               \n");
}
```

If you need the bootloader script ask me in the comment

I just want a script to call the bios if someone want to give me an totally other script which work for me it's a good answer.

Comment: Aren't you expected to switch to protected mode and forget all about the BIOS ever existing? That's what most protected-mode operating systems seem to do, like Linux in particular. Leaning on the BIOS is a bad plan unless you're just writing regular DOS apps.

Comment: Yes but I need to get vesa information and I don't know if it possible to make a driver

Comment: Can you do that *before* switching to protected mode in the first place, and save the info somewhere?  How do you make sure you haven't overwritten the original IVT and `0`, or any data or code the BIOS would need?

Comment: One thing you could do is dump the BIOS code, find out what you're calling, and port that code over. The BIOS itself isn't especially huge. It's also worth looking at what projects like Linux have done to interface with VESA, etc. as those systems were the norm back in the Linux 1.0 days.

Comment: I think it is possible but in my opinion it isn't the most simple way

Comment: Flipping in and out of protected mode could lead to all kinds of unpredictable side-effects. Does the processor not destroy all of the protected mode configuration you've done when reverting? You'll probably have to prepare that all over again, it'll be a very messy call.

Comment: I think it might be better to do this all in real-mode, understand what you have to do code-wise by dumping the BIOS and/or stepping through it in a debugger, then port that to protected mode. There's also a number of open-source BIOS implementations for things like VirtualBox that might help.

Comment: Yeah, but how can I switch graphic mode during the usation?

Comment: Do you think it is a better way to creat an driver?

Comment: I can't see a bug that would explain the symptoms, which makes me suspect there's a problem in something (code, linker script, ...) that wasn't shown. For alternatives; I'd recommend doing it in boot loader (while still in real mode). Don't "port a trace of what the video card's ROM for one specific video card" did and expect that to work on any other computer.

Comment: I found a new script on google, but now I have the same error, i think it is a gdt problem